# Qt SLOT macro used as function argument

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qt-signals, moc

I'm going through the calculator example that was installed with Qt 5.1.1 and there is a private function used to create button widgets (Button inherits QToolButton):

```
Button *Calculator::createButton(const QString &text, const char *member)
{
    Button *button = new Button(text);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, member);
    return button;
}
```

The example calls the above function to create several different buttons e.g.:

```
createButton(tr("Clear"), SLOT(clear()));
```

Where void clear() was declared as a private slot. I understand what the code is trying to do but I want to know why does passing SLOT(clear()) as the const char *member work. I can't seem to find much online that would explain using SLOT like that.

Comment: Is this still unresolved 0 months later??

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation of the connect method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#connect), the function signature expects the const char* type. These are the corresponding defines from QtCore:

```
Q_CORE_EXPORT const char *qFlagLocation(const char *method);
...
# define SLOT(a) qFlagLocation("1"#a QLOCATION)
# define SIGNAL(a) qFlagLocation("2"#a QLOCATION)
```

It is a bit more complex and you can see the details [in here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/61fda89cd1c1f95c408059c33a651407ff243ee1%3asrc/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs.h#L211), but I simplified it for the sake of the explanation and understanding.

This "old" signal-slot syntax is basically "string" based, and that is also the fundamental flaw with it. This was fixed in Qt 5, however. It is now closer what you seem to imply with your question so that you would rather expect it to be function or method pointers since you eventually pass such an element to the SLOT and SIGNAL moc tokens.

For completeness, the corresponding SIGNAL and SLOT tokens (i.e. Q_SLOTS, Q_SIGNALS, etc) are processed by the meta object compiler, aka. moc, the way that it puts those into the ".moc" files. You can see it yourself if you open those files up. For further details, look into the moc source code which can be found [in here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/61fda89cd1c1f95c408059c33a651407ff243ee1%3asrc/tools/moc).

Comment: "the SIGNAL and SLOT tokens are processed by the meta object compiler” - no, they just do some string mangling at runtime so that connect() can look up the signals and slots. They also pass the location of the connect call so connect() can print readable errors. moc (at build time) doesn’t process them at all.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: I updated to be more clear what I wished to express.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Wow this seems slightly over my head seeing how I'm a beginner at Qt but I'll understand over time. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Well I was gonna post this as a separate question based on the same calculator example. When creating button widgets such as the multiplication button, I saw the the string being passed to setText() as tr("\303\227"). Is "\303\227" a type of character encoding? What is it exactly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DanielJG: can you reprhase? Currently, I do not understand. There is no setText, etc, in your question.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: If you are referring to the original question, this is something completely different based on the same calculator example. I thought hopefully you wouldn't mind answering a question not related to the original post.